# Parsing json throwing null object

Tags: java, json

JSON INPUT(I have cut and paste it so there may be some errors in brackets).

```
 {"results":{"quote":[{"date":"2010-03-10","Date":"2010-03-10","Open":"16.51","High":"16.94","Low":"16.51","Close":"16.79","Volume":"33088600","Adj_Close":"16.79"},
{"date":"2010-03-09","Date":"2010-03-09","Open":"16.41","High":"16.72","Low":"16.40","Close":"16.53","Volume":"20755200","Adj_Close":"16.53"},
{"date":"2010-03-08","Date":"2010-03-08","Open":"16.32","High":"16.61","Low":"16.30","Close":"16.52","Volume":"30554000","Adj_Close":"16.52"},
{"date":"2010-03-05","Date":"2010-03-05","Open":"15.89","High":"16.38","Low":"15.89","Close":"16.06","Volume":"21415000","Adj_Close":"16.06"},
{"date":"2010-03-04","Date":"2010-03-04","Open":"15.55","High":"15.85","Low":"15.52","Close":"15.81","Volume":"22906000","Adj_Close":"}]}
```

JAVA CODE

```
System.out.println(inputLine1);
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( inputLine1 ); 
            JSONObject pilot = json.getJSONObject("results");        

            JSONArray jsonMainArr = pilot.getJSONArray("quote");  

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.size(); i++) 
            {  // **line 2**  
                JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);   
                String date = childJSONObject.getString("date");  
                String Date=childJSONObject.getString("Date");
                String Open=childJSONObject.getString("Open");
                String Close=childJSONObject.getString("Close");
                String High=childJSONObject.getString("High");
                String low=childJSONObject.getString("Low");
                String Volume=childJSONObject.getString("Volume");
                String Adj_close=childJSONObject.getString("Adj_Close");

                System.out.println(date);
                System.out.println(Open);


            }
```

It says a null object. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: 1) What is the exception exactly, which line
2) Make sure your json input is well formed

Comment: You have ' " ' missing at the end of your JSON string, please correct that.

Comment: Yeah that JSON is malformed.  Try pasting it into jsonlint.com and make sure it validates.  I have modified it to make it valid - http://pastebin.com/W9rkAi7k

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is not right. The last `"` is not closed:

```
{"results":{"quote":[..., {..., "Adj_Close":"}]}
```

This would cause that it's impossible to parse the value for `quote`, so the library returns `null` when you are expecting an array.